# losing when my mind's astray

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, lyrics

I was reading the lyrics of a song called "Dominoes" by Syd Barett, and couldn't understand what he was trying to convey in this verse "**Losing when my mind's astray**"

[Lyrics](https://genius.com/Syd-barrett-dominoes-lyrics)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about poetry / lyrics interpretation

Comment: Also Syd Barrett's surname has two 'r' letters.

Comment: which is why there is a lyrics tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know the song but I think if you consider it literally:  He is playing a game of dominoes with his girlfriend but is pre-occupied with their failing relationship - his mind is on other things [*gone astray*].  As a result, he is not concentrating on the game and, as a result, he loses.

It could also be a metaphor for their relationship - perhaps he has not been paying his girlfriend much attention, possibly looking at other women - playing another game... and, as a result their relationship is failing and he is losing her love...

**Go astray**: Wander off the right path or subject; also, wander into evil or error.

Comment: Thankx Mikal...

Comment: Regarding Barrett's mind being 'astray', it is possibly relevant that he quit Pink Floyd after becoming increasingly mentally erratic, even by the standards of the time for rock stars.